# Trying to get AJAX Autocomplete to work on dynamically created line items

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, autocomplete

I have an MVC project where I am trying to dynamically add line items to an order/invoice.  I want to be able to do an autocomplete on the service type field on each line, so when you start typing, the service gets pulled from a database query, and returns the name to the text field, and the ID to a hidden field on the line item.

The issue I am running into I can't figure out how to access the dynamically created fields.

First, this is how I create the line item (AJAX call from my view to a function in the controller that renders a partial view in my main view):

I have a view with a < ul > group (Create.cshtml):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ul id="ServiceOrderLineEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
    </ul>
    <p><a id="addAnother" href="#">Add another</a>
</div>
```

In my _Layout.cshtml file, I have the following script at the bottom (so it runs after any jquery scripts load).

```
<script>
$("#addAnother").click(function () {
    $.get('ServiceOrderLineEntryRow', function (template) {
        $("#ServiceOrderLineEditor").append(template);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

In my controller, I have the function:

```
public ActionResult ServiceOrderLineEntryRow()
    {
        return PartialView("CreateLineItem");
    }
```

I have my partial view that creates the < li > line items:

```
@model CRM.EntityModels.SERVICE_ORDER_DETAIL


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<li style="padding-bottom:15px">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("SOD"))
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/draggable-icon.png")" style="cursor: move" alt="" />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SERVICE_TYPE.NAME)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SERVICE_TYPE.NAME)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SERVICE_TYPE_ID)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UNIT_PRICE)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UNIT_PRICE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UNIT_PRICE)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QUANTITY)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QUANTITY)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QUANTITY)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EXTENDED_PRICE)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EXTENDED_PRICE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EXTENDED_PRICE)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TAXABLE)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TAXABLE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TAXABLE)

        <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Delete</a>
    }
</li>

}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I also have an overwritten HTML Helper that created the line item with an ID that has a GUID attached:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
/// <summary>
/// Generates a GUID-based editor template, rather than the index-based template generated by Html.EditorFor()
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
/// <param name="html"></param>
/// <param name="propertyExpression">An expression which points to the property on the model you wish to generate the editor for</param>
/// <param name="indexResolverExpression">An expression which points to the property on the model which holds the GUID index (optional, but required to make Validation* methods to work on post-back)</param>
/// <param name="includeIndexField">
/// True if you want this helper to render the hidden &lt;input /&gt; for you (default). False if you do not want this behaviour, and are instead going to call Html.EditorForManyIndexField() within the Editor view. 
/// The latter behaviour is desired in situations where the Editor is being rendered inside lists or tables, where the &lt;input /&gt; would be invalid.
/// </param>
/// <returns>Generated HTML</returns>
public static MvcHtmlString EditorForMany<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TValue>>> propertyExpression, Expression<Func<TValue, string>> indexResolverExpression = null, bool includeIndexField = true) where TModel : class
{
    var items = propertyExpression.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
    var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(propertyExpression);
    var htmlFieldNameWithPrefix = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName);
    Func<TValue, string> indexResolver = null;

    if (indexResolverExpression == null)
    {
        indexResolver = x => null;
    }
    else
    {
        indexResolver = indexResolverExpression.Compile();
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var dummy = new { Item = item };
        var guid = indexResolver(item);
        var memberExp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(dummy), dummy.GetType().GetProperty("Item"));
        var singleItemExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(memberExp, propertyExpression.Parameters);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(guid))
        {
            guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            guid = html.AttributeEncode(guid);
        }

        if (includeIndexField)
        {
            htmlBuilder.Append(_EditorForManyIndexField<TValue>(htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, guid, indexResolverExpression));
        }

        htmlBuilder.Append(html.EditorFor(singleItemExp, null, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", htmlFieldName, guid)));
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(htmlBuilder.ToString());
}

/// <summary>
/// Used to manually generate the hidden &lt;input /&gt;. To be used in conjunction with EditorForMany(), when "false" was passed for includeIndexField. 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
/// <param name="html"></param>
/// <param name="indexResolverExpression">An expression which points to the property on the model which holds the GUID index (optional, but required to make Validation* methods to work on post-back)</param>
/// <returns>Generated HTML for hidden &lt;input /&gt;</returns>
public static MvcHtmlString EditorForManyIndexField<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> indexResolverExpression = null)
{
    var htmlPrefix = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
    var first = htmlPrefix.LastIndexOf('[');
    var last = htmlPrefix.IndexOf(']', first + 1);

    if (first == -1 || last == -1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("EditorForManyIndexField called when not in a EditorForMany context");
    }

    var htmlFieldNameWithPrefix = htmlPrefix.Substring(0, first);
    var guid = htmlPrefix.Substring(first + 1, last - first - 1);

    return _EditorForManyIndexField<TModel>(htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, guid, indexResolverExpression);
}

private static MvcHtmlString _EditorForManyIndexField<TModel>(string htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, string guid, Expression<Func<TModel, string>> indexResolverExpression)
{
    var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}.Index"" value=""{1}"" />", htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, guid);

    if (indexResolverExpression != null)
    {
        htmlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}[{1}].{2}"" value=""{1}"" />", htmlFieldNameWithPrefix, guid, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(indexResolverExpression));
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(htmlBuilder.ToString());
}

public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, string collectionName)
{
    string itemIndex = GetCollectionItemIndex(collectionName);
    string collectionItemName = String.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex);

    TagBuilder indexField = new TagBuilder("input");
    indexField.MergeAttributes(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "name", String.Format("{0}.Index", collectionName) },
    { "value", itemIndex },
    { "type", "hidden" },
    { "autocomplete", "off" }
});

    html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(indexField.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    return new CollectionItemNamePrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, collectionItemName);
}

private class CollectionItemNamePrefixScope : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TemplateInfo _templateInfo;
    private readonly string _previousPrefix;

    public CollectionItemNamePrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string collectionItemName)
    {
        this._templateInfo = templateInfo;

        _previousPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
        templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = collectionItemName;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = _previousPrefix;
    }
}

private static string GetCollectionItemIndex(string collectionIndexFieldName)
{
    Queue<string> previousIndices = (Queue<string>)HttpContext.Current.Items[collectionIndexFieldName];
    if (previousIndices == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items[collectionIndexFieldName] = previousIndices = new Queue<string>();

        string previousIndicesValues = HttpContext.Current.Request[collectionIndexFieldName];
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(previousIndicesValues))
        {
            foreach (string index in previousIndicesValues.Split(','))
                previousIndices.Enqueue(index);
        }
    }

    return previousIndices.Count > 0 ? previousIndices.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

}

The helper class created a new input field when "Add Another" is clicked.  It attaches a GUID to the input name and id, so the input would be:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="SOD_f0b321d2-932b-4aeb-a433-70100355d3c6__SERVICE_TYPE_NAME" name="SOD[f0b321d2-932b-4aeb-a433-70100355d3c6].SERVICE_TYPE.NAME" value="" type="text">

<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SERVICE_TYPE_ID must be a number." data-val-required="The SERVICE_TYPE_ID field is required." id="SOD_f0b321d2-932b-4aeb-a433-70100355d3c6__SERVICE_TYPE_ID" name="SOD[f0b321d2-932b-4aeb-a433-70100355d3c6].SERVICE_TYPE_ID" value="" type="hidden">
```

This part works fine.  I click "Add Another" and it adds the line item.

Second, my problem is that I have this script that I was hoping would be able to bind the a SERVICE TYPE list to the dynamic service type name field:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ServiceName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetServiceList", "AccountServiceOrder")',
            datatype: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                    return {
                        label: val.Name,
                        value: val.Name,
                        serviceID: val.ID
                    }
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#ServiceID").val(ui.item.serviceID);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

It references this function in the controller:

```
public JsonResult GetServiceList(string term)
    {
        ServiceOrderDetailLogic serviceOrderDetail = new ServiceOrderDetailLogic();
        var ServiceList = serviceOrderDetail.GetServices(term);
        return Json(ServiceList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I know the above script isn't working.  It is not throwing an error, but I assuming that these lines:

```
$("#ServiceName").autocomplete({

$("#ServiceID").val(ui.item.serviceID);
```

need to say something like:

```
$("#SOD_f0b321d2-932b-4aeb-a433-70100355d3c6__SERVICE_TYPE_NAME").autocomplete({

$("#SOD_f0b321d2-932b-4aeb-a433-70100355d3c6__SERVICE_TYPE_ID").val(ui.item.serviceID);
```

Am I on the right track?  Is there a way to find that dynamic id for each line item as it is added and account for it to turn autocomplete on and look up that service list?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

I found a way to search for a particular text item to identify the HTML generated with the GUID (see the 1st comment in the code below).

I use the li:contains function to get the HTML of the element (see the 2nd comment below).

Then, I loop through each id attribute to collect the ID names that are GUID based (see the 3rd comment below).  This would find something like:

```
id="SOD_c1567fa3-b9da-4a76-a72f-6f2df36be4d8__SERVICE_TYPE_NAME"
```

At this point, I have the list of id nodes of text fields I need to update.  Next, I populate the autocomplete of the service text box (see the 4th comment below.  I can use # + svcName to find the correct field to autocomplete.

Then, I can map the results of the query to some response variables (see the 5th comment below).

Finally, I use the select function to set my GUID based text fields (and 2 checkbox field) to the response variable values (see 6th comment below).

I tested this, and it does work.

```
 <script>
    $("#addAnother").click(function () {
        $.get('ServiceOrderLineEntryRow', function (template) {
            $("#ServiceOrderLineEditor").append(template);
            var searchedText = "UNIT_PRICE"; //Search for some text in the list item to identify the HTML that contains the GUID
            $("li:contains('" + searchedText + "')").each(function (i, element) {
                var str = $(element).html(); //The HTML of the GUID based fields
                var svcName = "";
                var svcID = "";
                var unitPrice = "";
                var taxable = "";
                $(str).each(function (j, el) {
                    var tag = $(el).attr("id");//Set the ID tag names e.g.  id="SOD_c1567fa3-b9da-4a76-a72f-6f2df36be4d8__SERVICE_TYPE_NAME"
                    if (tag !== undefined)
                    {
                        if (tag.endsWith("SERVICE_TYPE_NAME")) {
                            svcName = tag;
                        }
                        if (tag.endsWith("SERVICE_TYPE_ID")) {
                            svcID = tag;
                        }
                        if (tag.endsWith("UNIT_PRICE")) {
                            unitPrice = tag;
                        }
                        if (tag.endsWith("TAXABLE")) {
                            taxable = tag;
                        }
                    }
                });

                $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#"+svcName).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetServiceList", "AccountServiceOrder")',
                        datatype: "json",
                        data: {
                            term: request.term
                        }, //Get the list of Services that narrow down as you type into the Service field
                        success: function (data) {      
                            response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                                return {
                                    label: val.NAME,
                                    value: val.NAME,
                                    serviceID: val.SERVICE_TYPE_ID,
                                    unitPrice: val.COST,
                                    taxable: val.TAXABLE //Map the results of the service query to the response
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert(error);
                        } 
                    })
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var item = ui.item;
                    if (item) {
                        $("#" + svcID).val(item.serviceID);
                        $("#" + unitPrice).val(item.unitPrice.toFixed(2));
                        $("#" + taxable).prop("checked",taxable);  //Set the GUID based text fields to the query results
                    }
                }
                });
            });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Screenshot 1 - Drop Down Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNqqb.png)

[Screenshot 2 - Unite Price / Taxable filled in when Service is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj5Nq.png)